# What is the Difference between Document.getelementByID and Jquery to get Dom Element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between

```
$("#<%=txtHourlyFromTime.ClientID%>")[0]
```

and

```
document.getElementById('txtHourlyFromTime').value
```

I'm new in Javascript and I don't know which one to use.

Comment: The first involves using the jQuery library. The second is a native browser API.

Comment: thank you for attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementById returns a DOM object.

```
document.getElementById('elementname')
```

is exactly the same as

```
 $('#elementname')[0]
```

Comment: only that '$' - will not work in Native Browser API and requires Jquery

Answer (score 4):

They are the same.

One that uses a $ sign is a [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).
While the [other](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp) one is native Javascript.